# RegExp help for converting hyperlinks

Tags: c#, regex, url

I am trying to come up with a regexp and have tried many combinations and searching to find a solution to convert non-hyperlinked addresses to hyperlinks.

ie

```
http://twitpic.com/abcdef http://www.smh.com.au askjhsd www.hotmail.com ks sd 
<a href="http://www.aaaaaaaa.com">aaaaaaaa</a>
```

I want the `http://twitpic.com/abcdef`,  `http://www.smh.com.au` and `www.hotmail.com` to be picked up but not the `http://www.aaaaaaaa.com` as it is wrapped around an `<a>` tag already.

I am currently using this regexp in C#

```
return Regex.Replace(input, @"(\b((http|https)://|www\.)[^ ]+\b)", 
   @" <a href=""$0"" target=""_blank"">$0</a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I have no idea how to make it exclude stuff already wrapped in `<a>` or `<img>`

Help :)

**EDIT**

For those reading this later, this is the final solution I came up with

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds to the input string a target=_blank in the hyperlinks
/// </summary>
public static string ConvertURLsToHyperlinks(string input)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        var reg = new Regex(@"(?<!<\s*(?:a|img)\b[^<]*)(\b((http|https)://|www\.)[^ ]+\b)");
        return reg.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(ConvertUrlsMatchDelegate));

    }
    return input;
}

public static string ConvertUrlsMatchDelegate(Match m)
{
    // add in additional http:// in front of the www. for the hyperlinks
    var additional = "";
    if (m.Value.StartsWith("www."))
    {
        additional = "http://";
    }
    return "<a href=\"" + additional + m.Value + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + m.Value + "</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
@"(?<!<\s*(?:a|img)\b[^<]*)(\b((http|https)://|www\.)[^ ]+\b)"
```

as your regex. The [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

The lookbehind assertion explained:

```
(?<!       # Assert that it's impossible to match before the current position:...
 <         # a <
 \s*       # optional whitespace
 (?:a|img) # a or img
 \b        # as an entire word
 [^<]*     # followed by any number of characters except <
)          # end of lookbehind
```

Comment: I did actually read that negative lookbehind assertion before posting this, but made no sense to me.. still doesnt. 

It works well for `<a>` but for its still catching it for `<img>`. How would I modify it so that if the address starts with `www`, the replace would add in `http://` ?

Comment: I overlooked the `img` tag bit - have edited my answer and added an explanation.

Comment: Awesome !!! That works and thx for the explanation. Finally, how would I modify it so that if the address starts with `www`, the replace would add in an extra `http://` ?

Comment: I would do that in two different regexes. One with the left side of the alternation, one with the right side - and only add `http://` to the replacement text for the latter one.